# angularJS: how to break the link between the model and the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wondering if it is possible at runtime to break the link between the model and the view.
In the following example, all the  are link together (through the *text* model). When I click the button I want to make angular to not update the last input any more (for example to start some jquery effects...).

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input ng-model="text"/><br/>
    <input ng-model="text"/><br/>
    <input ng-model="text"/><input type="button" value="<- break!" ng-click="???"/><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

My real case is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5JZPH/10/
In the jsfiddle example I expect that the old values (these that are fading) do not change any more when I press the '+' button.

Comment: What is the expected/desired behavior for the fiddle?

Comment: So if you remove the ng-model attribute it doesn't lose the association?

Comment: @Soubok Do you really need to break the link between the model and the view?
What about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5JZPH/13/ ?

Comment: @Soubok Better example: http://jsfiddle.net/5JZPH/14/

Comment: @ArtemAndreev, it's a good idea but I really need my "fading" input to be a part of the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fadeOut jQuery-cloned html element: http://jsfiddle.net/5JZPH/29/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <input type="button" value=" + " ng-click="index = index + 1"/>
    <input ng-model="index" smooth="index" style="display:block"/>
    [{{index}}]
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('smooth', function() {
    return {
        transclude: 'element',
        priority: 750,
        terminal: true,
        compile: function(element, attr, linker) {
            return function(scope, iterStartElement, attr) {

                var prevClone = null;

                scope.$watch(attr.smooth, function() {

                    var newScope = scope;

                    linker(newScope, function(clone) {

                        if ( prevClone ) {

                            newPrevClone = prevClone.clone();
                            prevClone.after(newPrevClone);
                            prevClone.remove();
                            newPrevClone.fadeOut(2000, function() { $(this).remove() });
                        }

                        iterStartElement.after(clone);

                        prevClone = clone;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    };
})
```